# Add twitter and facebook in eclipse

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse, twitter

how to add twitter and facebook in our eclipse project. I am doing an apps of video streaming. Thanks

Comment: use facebook and twitter api's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Facebook: You can use the [Facebook API directly](http://developers.facebook.com/android/), since it is really easy to understand and it works great.
- Twitter: I suggest you to use [this Twitter library](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html), better than its API.